# How to update image values by identifying unique locations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a image matrix named `final_img`. I have image location matrix with rows and columns is given below

```
a =

     1     1
     1     2
     2     1
     2     2
     3     1
     3     2
     1     1
     2     2
```

and values of this locations are

```
b =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
```

In above given locations, some are repeating eg: location `[1 1]` .  I can identify unique locations by using following code

```
[uniquerow, ~, rowidx] = unique(a, 'rows'); 
noccurrences = accumarray(rowidx, 1);
```

I need to update unique image locations by summing image location values. Eg: location `[1 1]` is repeating `twice` and corresponding value in `b` are `1` and `7`. So

`final_img(1,1)` should be `1+7=8;`

How can I implement this algorithm in MATLAB without using for loop?

Comment: What happens when you do `final_img(a(:,1), a(:,2)) = final_img(a(:,1), a(:,2)) + b`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: It won't work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function, which automatically adds all values corresponding to the same coordinates:

```
final_img = full(sparse(a(:,1), a(:,2), b));
```

This will create a matrix **as small as possible** according to the input.

---

If you want an ouput that is as small as possible with the resctriction that it be **square**:

```
M = max(a(:));
final_img = full(sparse(a(:,1), a(:,2), b, M, M));
```

---

If you want to **specify size** of the output:

```
M = 3;
N = 3;
final_img = full(sparse(a(:,1), a(:,2), b, M, N));
```

Comment: In my case final_img is a 3x3 matrix, but when I use your suggestion, I am getting 3x2 matrix. How can I use this for final_img of any size?

Answer (score 2):

You were so incredibly close:

```
[final_coords, ~, rowidx] = unique(a, 'rows'); 
final_vals = accumarray(rowidx, b);
```

Then to get it to image form:

```
% empty matrix with size of your image
final_img = zeros(max(final_coords,[],1));
% get linear indexes from coordinates
ind = sub2ind(size(final_img), final_coords(:,1), final_coords(:,2));
% fill image
final_img(ind) = final_vals;
```

Comment: And then use `sub2ind` to get linear indices into the image, and update those locations with `final_vals`.